# How does Rand work when starting at a number(36) with a max of 75

Tags: c++, random

I am creating a random number generator and whenever I run the current code block I always get a few numbers that go over the intended limit. The way it works is that I have a set of numbers that are randomly generated that go from 36-75, With adjusted numbers that are 5 higher and 5 lower than the original number. For example I will end up with numbers above 75. The highest being 105.
Here is just one of the 6 numbers.

```
//Displays picks for Number 4
pick4 = (rand() % 75) + 36;
if (pick4 == pick3)
    pick4 = (rand() % 75) + 36;
if (pick4 + 5 < 75 + 1)
{
if (pick4 - 5 > 0)
    {
        adjHighPick4 = pick4 + 5;
        adjLowPick4 = pick4 - 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a debugger and see what's going on. you can set up break point conditions etc, if you don't know how it is a good time to learn

Comment: Shouldn't `rand() % 75` be `rand() % 39` for that range of numbers you want?

Comment: @  πάντα ῥεῖ I wanted to get a set of random numbers starting at 36, with no numbers larger than 75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get a random integer from `A` to `B`, you just need a random integer from `0` to `B-A`, to which you add `A`. So, instead of `rand() % 75 + 36`, you should write `rand() % 39 + 36` (`A=36, B=75, B-A=39`)

Comment: Please stop propagating this `rand() % something` anti-pattern.

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean?

Comment: 1) `rand()` is a terrible RNG with no quality guarantees; 2) [the modulo operation introduces bias for most values of `something`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator). http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful